# Deploying Azure AD Authentication using MVC.Net on server

Tags: office365, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have developed a MVC.Net application where users can authenticate themselves against their AzureAD credentials i.e. Azure AD is the Login Provider. In this app we have also used Office 365 C#.Net API to read logged-in user's Calender events, mails etc.
This app works perfectly when running on local-machine i.e. when running from VS2013 but as we deploy it on Azure either as Web-Site or on VM created by Azure then after successful sign-in response is sent back to some .axd file and from there nothing happens.
Ex-> After signing-in control is sent back to :

http://unityocptestapp.cloudapp.net:8080/b578352e-717c-49bf-9de1-75992580896f.axd?code=AAABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGABFAsb03T_9-sn4QQBMHbklExQIuu01gbbLWvPAtMFy......................................

As you can see control is sent back to our web app (to some .axd file) and from there nothing happens further. i.e. I see a blank screen.

Can someone give us a clue of what wrong am I doing while deploying the app on server?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the return URL configured for your app in Azure AD?

Comment: The configured ReplyUrl on Azure is set as : http://unityocptestapp.cloudapp.net:8080. But there is an AppSetting in the Web.Config :

<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="/b578352e-717c-49bf-9de1-75992580896f.axd" />


This appsetting was created by VisualStudio tool only.

Comment: Ok, so finally I found the solution. In the appsetting "ida:RedirectURI" the value of this setting must have the Application Url when deployed on server. i.e.

On Server it should be :

 <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://whatever.com/b578352e-717c-49bf-9de1-75992580896f.axd" /> 

and, on local it should be:

 <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="/b578352e-717c-49bf-9de1-75992580896f.axd" />